# Java send some parameter to chrome extension plugin and call run this plugin

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-devtools, java

I have one plugin on my Chrome Browser Extension and i want to send some parameter to this and run this plugin.
So is that possible?

If yes so please guide me for the same.

I am using JAVA.

Comment: What do you mean? Run java code in chrome?

Comment: @Jägermeister I want to run plugin using java code.

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow you to run java code. End of story. Google willingly disabled support for applets many months ago for security reasons. For sure, they will not allow you to run a single line of java in their browser at all.